# Root object or no? What is the best practice for API responses?

Tags: android, ios, json, api

What is the best practice for JSON response data, nest the object within a parent object and include the root keypath or not?

```
{
    "activity": {
        "id": 20,
        "description": "a nice walk",
        "time_occurred": "2013-07-15T22:10:23Z",
        "duration": 45,
        "distance": 4.24,
        "location":"McDonalds"
    }
}
```

OR

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "description": "a nice walk",
    "time_occurred": "2013-07-15T22:10:23Z",
    "duration": 45,
    "distance": 4.24,
    "location":"McDonalds"
}
```

Seems like most HTTP frameworks (RestKit, GSON, etc) can handle either case, but I'd love to have a definitive answer on which approach is better and why. I feel like the first approach is more descriptive, which is always good, but the second approach is more lightweight and you *should* already know what object to map to based on the url path.

Note: I'm asking with specific reference to mobile app backends.

Comment: The second.  Less code to maintain going out and coming back in.  Only add the extra layer if there is a reason to name it or keep it separate from something.

Comment: If your primary consumer is a statically-typed language, there are a few things I would consider. I wrote about them here: http://john-sheehan.com/blog/dont-build-the-best-rest-api-build-the-best-http-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like **both** sides have traction.

#### In Favor of root elements

According to JSONAPI.org

> Its root key MUST be the same as the root key provided in the server's response to GET request for the collection.
>
> For example, assuming the following request for the collection of photos:

```
GET /photos

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "photos": [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Mustaches on a Stick"
  }]
}
```

#### In favor of no root element

Twitter does not when it uses a **settings** object

```
{
    "always_use_https": true, 
    "discoverable_by_email": true, 
    "geo_enabled": true, 
    "language": "en", 
    "protected": false, 
    "screen_name": "theSeanCook", 
    "show_all_inline_media": false, 
    "sleep_time": {
        "enabled": false, 
        "end_time": null, 
        "start_time": null
    }, 
    "time_zone": {
        "name": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", 
        "tzinfo_name": "America/Los_Angeles", 
        "utc_offset": -28800
    }, 
    "trend_location": [
        {
            "country": "United States", 
            "countryCode": "US", 
            "name": "Atlanta", 
            "parentid": 23424977, 
            "placeType": {
                "code": 7, 
                "name": "Town"
            }, 
            "url": "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2357024", 
            "woeid": 2357024
        }
    ], 
    "use_cookie_personalization": true
}
```

Instagram uses a combination of data and metadata, but does not use a root **user** object

```
{
  "meta":  {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data":  {
    "username": "obama",
    "bio": "",
    "website": "",
    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg",
    "full_name": "",
    "counts":  {
      "media": 30,
      "followed_by": 113,
      "follows": 130
    },
    "id": "2082346"
  }
}
```

Comment: "which approach is better and why" I don't think you explained that.

Comment: @BenMezger I don't know why. I am just adding some support to either side of the argument. Looks like JSONAPI.org is saying keep the root element while most other apis don't use it.

Comment: There is no 'better' or 'best' in this scenario. It's purely a taste thing

Answer (score 6):

## a) Root key that describes the resource/collection

This has the benefit of extra context in the response. The root key describes the resource or collection. I personally like this approach because it's obvious *what* the response document is describing -- you may argue that it's obvious from the endpoint,  but this isn't always the case.

## b) No root key that describes the resource/collection

This approach is more common in the wild. APIs that need to be high availability and fast will often strip out unnecessary data from the response document to reduce server load and request size. This typical of popular APIs that others look at when designing their own, and so you see it emulated for APIs that don't operate under the same conditions.

I don't buy the argument that lack of a root key makes the response easier to work with. It's an insignificant amount of effort to fetch data from a JSON object nested one level deep.

## c) Root key is `"data"`

When this question was posted, the [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/) had not yet reached v1.0 which means breaking changes were likely to occur. If you view their (stable) specification now, you'll see that [their stance on the root key](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level) has changed.

[The proposal for v1.0 Release Candidate 2 changed the top-level key to `"data"`.](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/341)

> Primary resources MUST now appear under the top-level `"data"` key.

Take for example this singular resource

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "The best article of all time",
      "author": "Kanye West"
    }
 }
```

I couldn't find the reason behind this, but I suspect it's because of consistency. No matter the resource, one can always fetch data from the document response because the top-level members are consistent, assuming the API follows the JSON API v1.0 specification.

Answer (score 3):

When you receive an object back from an external source (or anywhere for that matter), anything is possible.  You need to check the object to see how and if you can use it.

Keep it simple.

Twitter's API is simpler to consume than Facebook's simply because when you get a result, you don't have to null check it nearly as much.

Consider this code:

Twitter:

```
if (result.profile_image_url) {
    // use it
}
```

Vs. Facebook:

```
if (result.data && result.data.picture && result.data.picture.url) {
   // use it
}
```

IMO, the better solution is clear.  There's nothin wrong with root objects, but your API should make it simple and easy for clients to consume.